# If both $k$, $k+1$ are idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $k≠0$ then $n=2k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

> Question: If both $k$, $k+1$ are idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $k≠0$ then $n=2k$

My attempt: since  $k$, $k+1$ are idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ Hence we have,

$k^2\equiv k\mod n$

and $(k+1)^2\equiv k+1\mod n$

$\implies k^2+2k+1\equiv k+1\mod n$

$\implies k+2k+1\equiv k+1\mod n$

$\implies 2k\equiv 0\mod n$

So that $n\vert\text{ } 2k$.

**How to conclude that $n=2k$ ?**

(Above is an excercise from book 'Contemporary abstract algebra' by Gallian)

Comment: I guess that the equality is in $\mathbb Z_n$...

Comment: @Surb sir, but still how we get that, equality in $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: Transitivity with $0\equiv n\pmod{n}$

Comment: $\begin{align}n\mid k(k\!-\!1),k(k\!+\!1)&\iff n\ \mid\ (k(k\!-\!1),k(k\!+\!1))\ \ \ \text{[their gcd]}\\
 &\qquad\qquad\!\! =\, k(k\!-\!1,k\!+\!1)\\
&\qquad\qquad\!\!  =\, k(k\!-\!1,2)\\
&\iff\! \begin{cases} n\mid k,\,\ \ \text{ for $\,k\,$ even}\\ n\mid 2k,\ \text{ for $\,k\,$ odd}\end{cases}\\
\text{so it's not true as stated.} \end{align}$

Comment: @Boxwood , so what we get? $2k\equiv n\pmod n$ which implise $n\vert 2k-n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, so $2k\in\{0,1,\dots,2n-2\}$. (In fact, we have to assume $k+1<n$, too.) Since $n\mid 2k$ it follows that $2k=n$.

Comment: Sir, How it follows? Please help...

Comment: Non-zero multiples of $n$ are $n,2n,\dots$. But $2n>2k$, so $2k$, as a multiple of $n$ must be $n$.